# What is the easiest way to convert a folder full of PNG images into a video format?

Tags: video, png

The resulting video will be played over HDMI. The conversion to video must not modify the PNG frames in any way. I know that some video converters may interlace frames or do some other enhancement to make the video look smoother or for other reasons, but in this case, I don't want that.

Simple Mac application is preferred, but if thats not possible, then I'm ok with Python or the command line.

Answer (score 1):

I never tried it on Mac...
The simplest way I know, is to use [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) in command line.
There is ffmpeg version for Mac, I guess it's working the same way as in Windows.
Download "static FFmpeg binaries for Mac".

Read the following page first: [Using ffmpeg to convert a set of images into a video](http://hamelot.io/visualization/using-ffmpeg-to-convert-a-set-of-images-into-a-video/)

Also read this: [How to create an uncompressed AVI from a series of 1000's of PNG images using FFMPEG](https://superuser.com/questions/347433/how-to-create-an-uncompressed-avi-from-a-series-of-1000s-of-png-images-using-ff)

1. Make sure all png images are the same resolution.
2. Name the png files with ascending counter. Example: im0000.png im0001.png im0002.png...
3. Use ffmpeg to convert images to video.

If you choose to use lossless compression, you can use command line like this:

```
ffmpeg -r 30 -f image2 -i im%04d.png -c:v huffyuv -pix_fmt rgb24 output.avi
```

Of course this is just an example - you need to configure different parameters.

Expect large video files using lossless compression.
I recommend to use x264 compression with very low compression ratio, if all you need is displaying the video.

Comment: The "Using ffmpeg to ..." link is broken btw.